# Infopath question - for remote or offline users

Tags: infopath

I have a requirement where 400 field sales reps need to fill out a infopath form. Some has internet connection and some with poor and some none.

What are my option to submit data (including attachments) to sharepoint list? (using list email, have them send the form to an email then someone pushes the submit button?).

Please suggest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as you formulated your questions in context of submitting an Infopath form specifically to a sharepoint list, I do not believe you have any options except direct submission to a sharepoint list, at least OOTB (out of the box) in Infopath form templates of type/compatibility **Sharepoint List Form** which is created when you press Customize Form button in browser or Sharepoint List button  (< New < File on ribbon) in Infopath Designer. Such forms are rigidly linked to sharepoint list.

IMO, sending a Email (or any other ways of complications) require no less bandwidth and resources than submission of an Infopath form.
So, I would advise to exploit the offline functionality which is enabled by default when you create an Infopath form template (in Infopath Designer).

[image]

Comment: Let me try the offline option. and convince them. Thanks

Comment: Rebeca, thanks for accepting my answer. Infopath usage is a little bit tricky, depending on many requirement details so I updated my answer with "OOTB" reservation.